# Count first cells in a range of rows, which are higher than 0 and meet criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

For each column, I would like to count the amount of cells, which are higher than 0, appear for the first time in the row, and meet a criteria in one of the columns.

In this example, I would like to count the number of new customers for each month, the number of new customers in a specific region, and the number of customers in a specific industry.

Example:

[image: [example]

Can someone help?
Thanks

Comment: also, I should be able to add rows without messing up the formulas :-)

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

use SUMPRODUCT and MMULT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MMULT(--$D$4:E$8,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($D$4:E$8)^0))=E$4:E$8)*(E$4:E$8<>0))
```

The MMULT returns an array of the sum of the rows, this is then compared to the actual values and when they match it is the first time it is not `0` or `blank`

The SUMPRODUCT then keeps count where all are true.

For the other two we simply add another boolean to test the Region and Industry:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MMULT(--$D$4:E$8,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($D$4:E$8)^0))=E$4:E$8)*(E$4:E$8<>0)*($B$4:$B$8="A"))
=SUMPRODUCT((MMULT(--$D$4:E$8,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($D$4:E$8)^0))=E$4:E$8)*(E$4:E$8<>0)*($C$4:$C$8="A"))
```

Copy them over the columns.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting an error if I use the formula exactly the same way..

Comment: Try using Ctrl shift enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: that worked like a charm! thank you very much!!

Comment: I tried to apply this to my real sheet but failed miserably :-) The problem is, for each month I have 2 collumns (e.g. Planned & Forecast) and two counts below, and I didn't manage to apply the array to these ranges. Can you help apply the formula on the real sheet? For "Planned", I just need the count (orange cells) and for forecast I need the count only when Probability hits 100% (blue cells). See the excel sheet copied google here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bP4FV9xfKOsJr2KpXvkIriq3fJtwsbsI9fc6LuxDuAg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can someone help with this?

Answer (score -1):

You could try **`=COUNTIF(A1:A4,">0")`**
This is just generic formula. Hope it helps.

E.g. **`=COUNTIF(B2:E7,">0")`**

[image]

E.g. **`=COUNTIF(B2:E2,">0")`**

[image]

Comment: this doesn't work, it will just return the count of all the filled cells higher than 0, so the same customers will be counted multiple times across the months...I need every customer to be counted just once, once the first revenue is generated, and then not anymore in the following months..

Comment: ok sorry - good luck.